# Rust impl multiple times both for struct and traits

Tags: rust, trait-objects

Think below code, `impl` multiple times both for struct and traits:

```rust
mod m {
    pub trait Foo {
        fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("foo!"); }
    }
    
    pub trait Bar {
        fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("bar!"); }
    }
    
    pub trait Quux: Foo+Bar {
        fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("quux!"); }
    }
    
    pub struct X;
    impl X {
        pub fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("XXXXX self!"); }
    }
    impl Foo for X {}
    impl Bar for X {}
    impl Quux for X {}
}

use m::X;

fn main() {
    let x = X;
    x.xyzzy();
    {
        use m::Foo;
        x.xyzzy();  // prints "foo!"
    }
    {
        use m::Quux;
        x.xyzzy();  // prints "quux!"
    }
}
```

I want the result as below order:

```
XXXXX self!
foo!
quux!
```

But [the result](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d8aaa65e8a1940c315cb1d1717bb474c) will be:

```
XXXXX self!
XXXXX self!
XXXXX self!
```

What's wrong here and how to implement the goal?

Answer (score 2):

Because of how [method resolution](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) works, when you have a trait method and an inherent method with the same receiver (`&self`), you will always get the inherent method. If you want the trait method, you have to call it as an associated function.

```rs
{
    use m::Foo;
    Foo::xyzzy(&x);
}
{
    use m::Quux;
    Quux::xyzzy(&x);
}
```

Another thing you can do is make `X::xyzzy` an associated function.

```rs
impl X {
    pub fn xyzzy(_this: &Self) { println!("XXXXX self!"); }
}
```

And then call it as an associated function.

```rs
X::xyzzy(&x);
```

Then it won't be involved in method resolution, and the trait methods will be found when the traits are in scope.

Something that you may encounter is this rule:

> Then, for each candidate `T`, add `&T` and `&mut T` to the list immediately after `T`.

This means if you have a method that takes `&mut self`, a method that takes `&self`, and a method that takes `self` all in scope, then the `self` method will be called. However, this is not a clear or sustainable way to call a specific trait's method, The associated function syntax is certain to call the intended method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *fully qualified path*:

```rust
mod m {
    pub trait Foo {
        fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("foo!"); }
    }
    
    pub trait Bar {
        fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("bar!"); }
    }
    
    pub trait Quux: Foo+Bar {
        fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("quux!"); }
    }
    
    pub struct X;
    impl X {
        pub fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("XXXXX self!"); }
    }
    impl Foo for X {}
    impl Bar for X {}
    impl Quux for X {}
}

use m::X;

fn main() {
    let x = X;
    x.xyzzy();
    {
        use m::Foo;
        <X as Foo>::xyzzy(&x);  // prints "foo!"
    }
    {
        use m::Quux;
        <X as Quux>::xyzzy(&x);  // prints "quux!"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a cast, this is called _fully qualified path_, or _UFCS_ (_Universal Function Call Syntax_). https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/call-expr.html#disambiguating-function-calls.